# Do you know if Citadel or Fortress supports <polyline>?

Tags: gazebo-citadel, ignition-fortress, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found this from http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=geometry

I wanted to try this out on Citadel and Fortress so I did a simple section:

> ```
> <model name='test'>
> ```

```
  <link name = "test_shape">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
    <visual name="'visual">
      <geometry>
        <polyline>
          <point> 1 1</point>
          <height> 5</height>
        </polyline>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <polyline>
          <point> 1 1</point>
          <height> 5</height>
        </polyline>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
</model>
```

Yet it created multiple errors:

```
bwuk@robots:~/smart-car/simulation/model/sdf$ ign gazebo -r test.sdf 
Warning [GenericJoint.hpp:1480] [GenericJoint::setRestPosition] Value of _q0 [0], is out of the limit range [0.1, 3.1] for index [0] of Joint [Joint].
[Err] [Conversions.cc:245] Geometry type [0] not supported
[Err] [Conversions.cc:245] Geometry type [0] not supported
Error [parser.cc:796] Error parsing XML from string: Error=XML_ERROR_PARSING_ATTRIBUTE ErrorID=8 (0x8) Line number=4: XMLElement name=visual
[Err] [Conversions.cc:245] Geometry type [0] not supported
[GUI] [Err] [Model.hh:73] Unable to unserialize sdf::Model
[GUI] [Err] [Conversions.cc:360] Geometry type [0] not supported
[Err] [SceneManager.cc:739] Unsupported geometry type
[Err] [SceneManager.cc:393] Failed to load geometry for visual: 'visual
Error [parser.cc:796] Error parsing XML from string: Error=XML_ERROR_PARSING_ATTRIBUTE ErrorID=8 (0x8) Line number=4: XMLElement name=visual
[GUI] [Err] [Model.hh:73] Unable to unserialize sdf::Model
[GUI] [Err] [Conversions.cc:360] Geometry type [0] not supported
Error [parser.cc:796] Error parsing XML from string: Error=XML_ERROR_PARSING_ATTRIBUTE ErrorID=8 (0x8) Line number=4: XMLElement name=visual
[GUI] [Err] [Model.hh:73] Unable to unserialize sdf::Model
[GUI] [Err] [Conversions.cc:360] Geometry type [0] not supported
[GUI] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:739] Unsupported geometry type
[GUI] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:393] Failed to load geometry for visual: 'visual
```

I even ran `ign sdf --check test.sdf`

and it returns `Valid.`

So...what did I do wrong? How do you use polyline in ignition?

I hope this is not bug since I already created more than 10 issues in Github already lol :'(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27837/do-you-know-if-citadel-or-fortress-supports-%3Cpolyline%3E?/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

They added it on Citadel/Fortress now. Thank you, gazebo team!!!

https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo3/examples/worlds/polylines.sdf

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2022-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0